# transferring php form data to a js window

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms, window.open

I am designing a game with javascript and jquery. In my game when a player talks to another character it opens the text as an external file using the `window.open('')` function. At the beginning of the game the user has to enter a name for their character it is then processed by php: 
`<form action="play.php" method="get">

<input type="text" name="name"/><input type="submit" value="confirm"/>

</form>`.
As I said before when a player talks to another player it opens the external file but what I am asking is how to transfer the form data to the external window opened with `window.open('')` I have already tried 
`function txtone()

{
window.open('txtone.php?name=<?php echo $_GET["name']; ?>')
}`

but it didn't work. So basically what I want in the end is an external window opened with `window.open('txtone.php')` that can receive the php data from the page it was opened from 
(rather than opening txtone.php it would open txtone.php?name=example).
Edit: I have an idea I could send a php variable to the child window opened with window.open but I have no idea how to do this mabye with `window.opener`?

Answer (score 3):

Did you try `window.open('txtone.php?name=<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_GET["name"]); ?>')`

Answer (score 0):

```
function txtone() {
    window.open('txtone.php?name=<?= $_GET["name"] ?>');
}
```

Comment: That brought me to txtone.php?name=<?=%20$_GET["name"]%20?>.

Answer (score 0):

When the user "logs in" - so to say - with his user name at the beginning of your game, maybe try to save the name in a Cookie and read it when he wants to talk to others and give his name to window.open with JS.

```
window.open('txtone.php<?php echo $_GET["name'}; ?>')
```

^That line has a typo at the end (} instead ]) and would also lead to a result of:

```
txtone.phpSomeUserName
```

You're missing the parameter there (if that's in your code like that, most likely your culprit). Probably you intended to have something like

```
txtone.php?username=<?php echo "someUsername"; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is a bit off

Change

```
window.open('txtone.php<?php echo $_GET["name'}; ?>')
```

To

```
window.open('txtone.php<?php echo $_GET['name']; ?>')
```

Also make sure you're passing a value to your name input