# Converting a PHP variable to a JavaScript variable

Tags: javascript, php, forms, window.open

I am making a pop up window with JavaScript using `window.open()`. The page to be opened should be stored in a variable.

That variable's name is determined using a PHP `<form>`. When the user clicks "confirm", it brings them to `play.php?name=userinput`, and when the `window.open` function is executed, it currently opens `txtone.php`. But I want it to open `txtone.php?name=userinput`, including that argument.

I can retrieve the value from the parent window (`name=userinput`), using a PHP variable, but I need to transform it into a JavaScript variable, and then use `window.open(name);` (The variable's name is `name`).

So I am basically asking how do I convert a PHP variable into a JavaScript variable.

Comment: You could make a pause, every once in a while

Comment: Use sentences in your question. Include whitespace.

Comment: possible duplicate of another of OPs questions: [transferring php form data to a js window](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19473145/transferring-php-form-data-to-a-js-window)

Answer (score 12):

Making a PHP variable available in JavaScript happens when the page is generated. For example, assume you have a php variable called $name and you want a JavaScript variable called name. You normally define your JavaScript variable as:

```
var name='some value';
```

Instead, you will insert PHP:

```
var name='<?php echo $name; ?>';
```

Now, the value of $name in your PHP is also the value of name in your JavaScript at the moment that the page is dynamically created.

UPDATE: When I answered this, I should have explained further...

While the JavaScript and PHP variables have the same value, they are NOT the same variable. If you update $name in your PHP after your print the value to the JavaScript source code, it will not alter the JavaScript value. Similarly, if you change the value of the JavaScript variable, it will not change the value of the PHP variable. In other words, they are two completely separate and unrelated variables. The code above simply copies the value from PHP to JavaScript.

Answer (score 4):

Try this :

where `spge` is variable in `js`

```
var spge = '<?php echo $status ;?>';
```

Answer (score 1):

//suppose

```
<?php $tochange="from php to js" ?>
```

some where

```
//Head

    <script>

    function change(){

    var temp = document.getElementById("change").innerHTML;

    alert ("temp");

    }

    </script>

//body
<body  onload="change()" >


//create a invisible tag in body php document

    <span id="change"><?php echo $tochange ?></span>


.....
```